# C# TCP traffic approach between apps on the same IP and port?

Tags: c#, xml, tcp

I have been given an interface to develop which is stumping me a bit on the communication side.  It's been a while since I have fooled with TCP and I am having trouble getting my head around it.

My companies app (let's call it APP1) has the responsibility of sending data (xml via TCP) to another company's app (APP2).  Additionally, there will sometimes be traffic received (unsolicited) from APP2 by APP1 for updates that occurred in APP2.  I have zero control over APP2.  APP2 has to run on the same client PC as APP1.  Additionally, APP2 only has the ability to specify one port (we will use 9000) and one IP (usually 127.0.0.1) for traffic.

Using a TCP server, I am create a listener for traffic on port 9000.  I also plan to use that tcp server to send data.  However, when I .Send() my listener picks up the traffic because the destination for APP2 is 127.0.0.1.  I am not sure how I can get data to APP2 while also listening on the same port.

Additionally, if APP2 is on a different machine, everything works fine, it's only when sharing the same client environment that I am struggling.

Can anyone give me an idea of how to approach this?

Comment: Can you add a distinct header to your packages when sending? You would be able to discard those by inspecting the data.

Comment: Can you post your code where you create the sender.  It sounds like you aren't configuring it properly.

Comment: The TCP listener is capable of receiving multiple connections simultaneously.  Use the ASYNC method.  The accept method is called once for every new connection and the new connection is the socket.  So in the Accept method add the new socket to a List.  Then send the results back to the same socket that message was received.  I normally get the remote endpoint which contains the IP of the client and create state class that contains the socket, and IP address.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example